# C# How to process large byte arrays?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I`m receiving packets in my TCP Client, and this is how it works:
Server send a packet where the first two bytes are the packet size information.
Ex: 0C 00 = 12 bytes length.
But, there is a problem (happens alot), the server send a lot of 'packets' in the same buffer, and sometimes the buffer is missing bytes that will arrive in the next buffer.
What do I have right now:
A Simple tcp socket with Send/Recv.
A List to handle bytes where I add bytes with .AddRange. 
A PostProcess after 'cutting' arrays.

It works, but sometimes things arent right(cliente looks like ignoring packets)
Sorry for my bad english, and here is my code:

```
bufferList = new List<byte>();
private void WaitData(IAsyncResult ar)
    {

        try
        {
            Int32 size = socket.EndReceive(ar);
            if (size > 0)
            {
                Array.Resize(ref buffer, size);
                bufferList.AddRange(buffer);
                dataProcessor();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Functions.logMessage(logger, "Erro no wait data " + ex.Message, 1);
        }
        finally
        {
            buffer = new byte[100000];
            socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, WaitData, null);
        }

    }
 public void dataProcessor() //byte[] data
    {
            while (bufferList.Count > 0)
            {
                int size = (Int32)(BitConverter.ToInt16(bufferList.Take(2).ToArray(), 0));
                postProcess(bufferList.Take(size).ToArray());
                bufferList.RemoveRange(0, size);
            }
    }
```

Comment: are you using .net core? if so look at `System.Memory.Span`

Comment: Oh, I'll take a look. Thanks!!!!!!